# How to make AsyncWrite movable when spawning async task?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a function where the user can pass in an object `writer` that implements AsyncWrite as an argument.

I save that `writer` and when needed, I start an asynchronous task to call the `write()` interface of that `writer` to send the data out.

For my needs, I simplified a test program in which I start a TCP server. i simulate the above required writer object with a TCP Stream client.

The TCP server receives the corresponding data and prints it out. Now it is the under_test() function that does not compile. It prompts the error.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWrite, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

#[tokio::test]
async fn test_spawn_move_writable() {
    async fn under_test<T: AsyncWrite>(writer: Arc<Mutex<T>>, data: &[u8]) {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let writer = writer.lock().await;
            writer.write(data);
// `T` cannot be unpinned
// consider using `Box::pin`
        })
        .await
        .unwrap();
    }

    let addr = "127.0.0.1:3000";
    let tcps = TcpListener::bind(addr).await.unwrap();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let (mut client, caddr) = tcps.accept().await.unwrap();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                let mut buf = vec![0; 16];
                loop {
                    let size = client.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
                    println!(
                        "{:?}> {}",
                        caddr,
                        std::str::from_utf8(&buf[0..size]).unwrap()
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });

    let tcps = TcpStream::connect(addr).await.unwrap();
    let tcps = Arc::new(Mutex::new(tcps));
    for data in [b"hello", b"world", b"rustl", b"tokio"] {
        under_test(tcps.clone(), &data[..]).await;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to address this is to require that `T: Unpin`, which shifts the burden of possibly pinning a value to the caller, where it should be anyway.  Since `TcpListener` implements `Unpin`, no further changes are necessary to resolve this problem.

However, when you fix this problem you'll run into two more problems:

- `tokio::spawn` might send the future to another thread, so `T` must also be `Send`.  That's easily fixed by adding the bound `T: Send`.
- `tokio::spawn` places no guarantee on how long the future will live, which means it must be `'static`.<sup>1</sup>  This is easily fixed for `T` by specifying `T: 'static`, but for the same reason you also have to change the type of `data` to `&'static [u8]`.

Finally, you need `writer` in the closure to be mutable to call `write` on it, so you could just stick a `mut` after the `let`.  Or, perhaps simpler, remove the `writer` variable and just chain the `write` call after the `await`, as in `writer.lock().await.write(data);`.

All of the problems are fixed in this version:

```
async fn under_test<T: AsyncWrite + Unpin + Send + 'static>(
    writer: Arc<Mutex<T>>,
    data: &'static [u8]
) {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        writer.lock().await.write(data);
    })
    .await
    .unwrap();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3f8433a45c4643ee960ace284fea903))

---

<sup>1</sup> The future can't borrow from non-static sources because it *could* outlive any of them.  That's not possible in this case because you `await` the returned `JoinHandle`, but the compiler is bound by `tokio::spawn`'s own requirement that the future be `'static`, so that is enforced.

Comment: To avoid the `'static` bound you can try the crate `tokio-scoped` or `async-scoped`.

Comment: @rodrigo Sure, though the use of `tokio::spawn` seems redundant here anyway since the returned `JoinHandle` is immediately awaited.